# How to hide the object emitting particles?

Tags: rendering, particles

I have a surface with particles. But I don't want to see the original object in the render. How to fix it?

Transparency, other collection / scene doesn't work.

Comment: The tile of this question is misleading, not worded correctly. It should say: How to hide the original object used by the particle system?

Comment: Did you ever solve this, I'm having the same problem now while learning Blender.  How to hide the template object/collection used for defining particles.

Comment: [This solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/201652/15265) worked for me. Using 3.1.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two settings `Show emitter`:

1. in the **Render** section works only for the final render
2. in the **Viewport Display** section for the current view port

However when you un-check the `Show emitter` in the **Viewport Display** section both emitter and particles may disappear. You need to re-select `Dispaly As` as **Rendered** and then only the particles will show.

To hide the original object or collection used for particle instances just hide them in Scene collection window.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

At the particle settings under the Render section untick the Show Emitter box.

[image]

Comment: As I understand, it hides emitter. Maybe i described my situation incorrect. I have particles (A) which made from collection of objects (B) . All these stuff has place on surface (C) on which applied particles. I want to see on render A and C, without B

Comment: In 3.1, in my case: Unchecking `Render` | `Show Emitter` behaves erratically, but never in the expected way: Sometimes it hides both the emitting object and the rendered particles, [sometimes it hides nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkFzj.png). Add to that viewport and render states are not consistent, e.g. both visible in the viewport but both hidden in the render.

Comment: @mins This might be because you have not unchecked `Show Emitter` in `Viewport Display` as well.

Answer (score 8):

I had same problem when I was following tutorials and I couldn't hide emitter object for during render(but during the viewport it was working). I found that turn off "Show Instancer" under object properties did the trick for Eevee render setting. I don't know if works in cycles; my PC is potato... good luck guys :P
[image]

P.S. I'm using Blender 2.90.1

Comment: In 3.1. Unchecking as you show worked for me, At the same time `Show Emitter` in the particles system could be checked or unchecked without influence on the result. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just hide the original objects, particle system objects should stay visible even with original ones hidden (not rendering). Just don't delete them.

Comment: Yes, it hides for viewport, but i still see them in render(

Comment: There are 4 icons in a row in Outliner for each object: Eye (hide in viewport), Cursor (Disable selection), Monitor (Disable in Viewport) and Camera (Disable in Renders). It seems that you need to uncheck the last one, can also disable them all and original objects should not be visible anywhere.

Comment: Strange, before I did the same, it hid all objects. And now it has suddenly become as it should. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: "*There are 4 icons in a row in Outliner for each object*" and labels vary: "Exlude", "Hide" and some "Disable". Frankly I can't figure out the difference between them (this is not just visible in viewport vs visible in render), nor if one has a higher priority, specially in the case of active objects like particle emitters where multiple aspects are to be considered: Emitter visibility, particles visibility, emitter ability to create particles, etc, and that independently for viewport and render. Very obscure.

Answer (score 0):

legitimately made an account because I managed to figured it out while I had this open but try unchecking the check box beside the collection NOT! the icons but the check box[image]

this is what worked for me for some reason and I'm definitely not entirely knowledgeable in this software but it worked so I thought I'd post it

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Unchecking the box hides the whole collection from view layer. So anything inside it won't be shown in viewport or render. Just so you know why it works like that :).

Comment: I mean the main problem appeared when I tried hiding it from the final render, but then the particle system stopped working entirely, and for some reason the particle system worked only when the original collection was shown in its stationary position in the render port. I assume that when I disable the view in final render it should hide my objects from view but not stop the whole particle system working I think

Answer (score -2):

Yeah. I suddenly started having trouble with this today and it plagued me ALL day. Just doing weird stuff. My initial problem was how I had things arranged in collections but that was causing other issues...maybe? I think I just fixed it by LEAVING EVERYTHING ALONE and JUST turning off the show emitter button in the render section of the particles settings. Everything is else is checked as ON. And now it seems to be working. I hope this works for everyone because it's the simplest possible fix, eh?