# How can i disable a particle base object from render?

Tags: particles

So i made a bunch of trees and they all use particle systems for the foliage. The base foliage object that i used for the particles gets render with the scene, but if i disable its collection or the single object from render then all the trees lose their foliage as well in the render.
I'm looking for a way to hide only the base foliage mesh i used for the particle systems without losing also the particle systems in the render. I know that i could move what i don't need out of the camera view, but i want to keep it as simple and tidy as possible because it's a really heavy scene.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide the object emitting particles in a render in Blender 2.80?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129173/how-to-hide-the-object-emitting-particles-in-a-render-in-blender-2-80)

Comment: No, you might have misunderstood the question because i'm still learning english, lemon answered (i had to create a new collection for the particles to fix the problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable *"show emitter"*

[image]

Will have effect in rendering only (not when viewport shading is set to rendered).

Seems I've misunderstood the question. To hide the original particle object, put it in another collection and disable this collection for rendering.

[image]

Note that if the PS instances are based on a collection, move this collection in another one and disable this last one for rendering.

Comment: but this just hides the trunks, i want to render the trees but not the original foliage meshes i made to be duplicated in the particle systems if that makes sense. the ones that you select in the "render as" particle settings.

Comment: Oh, ok. In this case put this base mesh(es) in a collection and disable the collection for rendering.

Comment: that's what i did, but it removes the particles systems from the render. if i disable the base collection from render i see only the trunks of the trees in render

Comment: Trunk and this object should be in two separated collections. Trunk in rendered one and this base object disable rendering one.

Comment: yeah the collections are already separated but if i disable base i lose particle systems in render

Comment: is it because i'm using the render as option collection instead of object? might that be the problem? I'm sadly forced to do that because for some reason render as object option doesn't works for me in this case

Comment: Should not. Here is an example: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=8goqB9bw" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/8goqB9bw/)

Comment: If it is a collection put it in another one. and disable this last one

Comment: It works! thank you so much i would have never thougth that could fix it