# Making objects invisible

Tags: particles

I am new to blender and this forum so be gentle.

I am designing a planet with the typical "Saturn-ring". I put some stones via particle-system onto the ring. Now I want to only show the stones not the circle mesh I put them on.

How can I do that?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Hi. When the stone-particles are emitted from the circle there is an option. Have a look here: [How to hide the object emitting particles in a render in Blender 2.80?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/129173/107598)

Comment: Thank you very much!