# How to Create Procedural stars using nodes for EEVEE

Tags: modeling, node-editor, procedural

Is there a way to create procedural stars using nodes? I learnt a few days ago, how to make stars for the background using nodes set up, but what I'd like to know is if it's possible to make scattered stars from a mesh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the stars with icosphere and this kind of material (mix between *Emission* and *Transparent* nodes with a *Layer Weight* as factor, remember to choose *Alpha Blend* in the *Material Settings > Blend Mode*):

[image]

Then create a cube, give it a *Particle System / Hair*, *Emit From > Volume*, with the icosphere as render object, give it scale randomness, disable the *Show Emitter* option, or give your cube a transparent shader.

[image]

At last, give it a glare effect in the *Compositor*:

[image]

Comment: Worked well, but how did you get your cube opaque? I can still see my one. https://ibb.co/KwfX8WW

Comment: you can either disable Show Emitter in the Particle panel, or choose a transparent material (don't forget to choose Alpha Blend in the Material Settings, like for the stars)

Comment: Unchecking the shower Emitter didn't fully work, until I googled this here as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129173/how-to-hide-the-object-emitting-particles-in-a-render-in-blender-2-80

Comment: mmh ok, it works for me though, I don't know what's happening

Comment: Not for the first time, curious about why you prefer to use hair, than an ordinary particle system. My ignorance... clumping? physics?

Comment: if think both work but Hair is probably easier to set for this kind of purpose?

Comment: typically for this kind of purpose where you don't need to move the particles it seems more logical to use hair, no?

Comment: In regards to moonboots answer - to make the cube transparent, make sure you uncheck show emitter in both render and view port tabs