# Particle System: "Show Emitter" unchecked but still visible in export file

Tags: rendering, particles, export, .fbx, visibility

I want my particle system's emitter, in my case a plane, to be invisible in the exported file (for Unity). This question was already asked here: [How to hide the object emitting particles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129173/how-to-hide-the-object-emitting-particles). I tried the solutions of the question: Uncheck "Show Emitter" checkbox in rendering tab of the particle system. However, when I export the file as an FBX, the plane is still visible.

What could be the mistake I made? Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Unchecking `Show Emiter` will only disable the object for rendering but if you export the mesh, it's still going to be there.

Comment: Ok, so how can I export the model with an invisible emitter?

Comment: Particles are a blender thing. It can't be exported as an fbx as far as I know. If you want it as an fbx, you will need to somehow convert it into a mesh then export it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works fine to export the particle system - I can see all the hair particles in the fbx file. The only thing I want to change is the visibility of the emitter plane. Should I do it with an transparent material?

Comment: I also tried converting them into a mesh, but its much more inefficient (which reduces the performance in unity very much).

Comment: Using hair particles in Unity or in any other game engine is generally a bad idea as it's always performance heavy. It's better to use hair cards or polyhair.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134785/discussion-between-philale-and-mqbaka-mqbaka).